# What license woud an ex-military aircraft (E.g, L-39) go under according to the UK-CAA, an EASA licence or a non-EASA license?

Tags: military, regulations, ppl, easa, caa-uk-regulations

I've been looking around for the sale of ex-military jets, to own and fly, namely an Aero Vodochody L-39 Albatros, and so out of interest had a look at the CAA website for infomation on licenses, training and general ownership etc, and across the terms EASA and non-EASA licenses, I rougly understood the meaning of them, but am unsure as to which license I would need to own and L-39.

Whilst asking this, I would be appreciative if anyone could give me some general tips and advice on owning an ex-militatry jet trainer and the kind of courses/training I'd have to undertake to own and fly it. Thank you in advance.

Please edit if I have left something important out or anything like that.

Comment: [Related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/9411/62)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [CAP 632](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/modalapplication.aspx?appid=11&mode=detail&id=135)

> 6.1 Ex-military aircraft on the UK register with a ‘Permit-to-Fly’ may be piloted by either private or professional licence holders. Pilots must hold a current civil licence with a current civil class or type rating appropriate to the ex military type[s] being flown or where no civil type rating exists, an Aircraft Type Rating Exemption from the need to hold a type rating.
>    Any questions relating to licence matters should be addressed to CAA PLD

...

> - Any turbine-powered aeroplane - To fly an ex-military turbine-powered 
>     aeroplane a pilot must hold an Aircraft Type Rating Exemption. See paragraph 
>     6.7 for details of obtaining an Aircraft Type Rating Exemption

and so on.

Ex-military aircraft are non-EASA aircraft. [Ref](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Learning-to-fly/What-can-I-fly-with-my-licence-/)

Comment: So the aircraft has to be ex-british and I would have to have flown it in the military beforehand, or be a commercial pilot?

Comment: @anonymous. 1) AFAIK non-British aircraft can be registered in the UK and many are. 2) No. 3) No.

Comment: Thank you very much for your clarification and original answer, I appreciate it.