# How can I get a license to fly an F14?

Tags: pilot-certification, f-14

Say I have $x million to buy an F-14 Tomcat and am physically fit (I think) to be able to fly it. Is there a short pilot training course I can attend to get licensed to fly it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What licenses/endorsements or type ratings do you need to fly a fighter jet?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/64797/what-licenses-endorsements-or-type-ratings-do-you-need-to-fly-a-fighter-jet)

Comment: Define "short". Current US Navy training to fly their strike aircraft takes about two years ([Source](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_Naval_Aviator))

Comment: Getting licensed to fly an F-14 is one thing; *renting* an F-14 to fly is another.

Answer (score 0):

Anybody with the resources and connections to buy an F-14 could probably find a former Navy CFI to get them up to speed.  Otherwise no, there is no existing course you can simply attend.  There just isn't enough demand to run such a business.